# Eclipse Plugin dependent upon jar and therefore make a plugin from the dependency: what about its dependencies?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

It is my understanding that if an Eclipse plugin is dependent upon a jar, the jar should be made into a plugin. I did this: one detail is that I made a jar-of-jars from the jar so that it would have all of its dependencies. Does it make sense that I needed to do that and would those dependencies in turn have to be made into plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that a plugin needs must be one or other plugin.

You can put multiple jars in to one plugin if you wish. Just make sure all the jars are listed in the `Bundle-ClassPath` in the MANIFEST.MF and also in the build.properties file. Use `Export-Package` to say which packages are available to other plugins.

For example this MANIFEST is for Apache Derby jars:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: %Bundle-Name
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.derby
Automatic-Module-Name: org.apache.derby
Bundle-Version: 14.1.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: %Bundle-Vendor
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-9
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/derby.jar,
 lib/derbyclient.jar,
 lib/derbynet.jar,
 lib/derbytools.jar
Export-Package: org.apache.derby.agg,
 org.apache.derby.authentication,
 org.apache.derby.catalog,
 org.apache.derby.catalog.types,
 org.apache.derby.client,
 org.apache.derby.client.am,
 org.apache.derby.client.am.stmtcache,
 org.apache.derby.client.net,
 org.apache.derby.database,
 org.apache.derby.diag,
 org.apache.derby.drda,
 org.apache.derby.io,
 org.apache.derby.jdbc,
 org.apache.derby.mbeans,
 org.apache.derby.mbeans.drda,
 org.apache.derby.osgi,
 org.apache.derby.security,
 org.apache.derby.shared.common.error,
 org.apache.derby.shared.common.i18n,
 org.apache.derby.shared.common.reference,
 org.apache.derby.tools,
 org.apache.derby.vti
```

This is including 4 jars in a 'lib' folder.

Comment: It sounds like if I convert a jar to a plugin, then all the jars it depends must themselves be plugins but if that is true, must all those jars be converted?

Comment: Yes all the dependencies must be in a plugin, Eclipse/OSGi will not look anywhere else. You can put them all in the one plugin if nothing else is going to use the jars.

Comment: *In* a plugin but not separate plugin projects, right?

Comment: You can put it all in one plugin or have multiple plugins with dependencies between them - it is up to you. If nothing else will use the jars one plugin makes sense. If other plugins might want to use things use multiple plugins.